# Converting htmldb_Get to apex.server.process

Tags: jquery, oracle, upgrade, oracle-apex

We have upgrade apex from 3.2 to 5.1.1. We are using a function htmldb_get in our jquery. But this function has been desupported by oracle in the latest release. Now we are trying to rewrite the same with apex.server.process (oracle recommendation). Can someone advice on how to rewrite the below statement?

```
var a=new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=DUMMY",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`htmldb_Get.get` is a synchronous api. It means that when you have called `get()` you will have the result at hand and the following code will have access to that result.
The new api is asynchronous. The result will get fetched but may or may not be available immediately. This is the most common mistake people make when moving to this new api.

You didn't post more code, but take note that this is important. Right now you've only posted how you set up the `htmlDb_Get` object. You haven't called `get` yet.

So for example, say the code looks like this:

```
var a=new htmldb_Get(null,&APP_ID.,"APPLICATION_PROCESS=DUMMY",&APP_PAGE_ID.);
var result = a.get();

var result2 = doSomethingWithResult(result);
...
$s('Px_ITEM1', result2);
```

It isn't enough to "simply" replace `.get()` with `apex.server.process`. It doesn't map or work that way. You have to take in account that the returning of the result may take a while. The API (and how ajax goes) simply instantiates a call which in some point in the future returns the result. It does not block the code (= thread) unlike a synchronous call (which also blocks the browser's UI). So if you replace the above and call result-dependent code right after, assuming the result is there, will cause you head-scratching moments as in: "sometimes it's there and other times it isn't - what's happening?".
So cue the "done" function on apex.server.process, which executes when the call finishes up (= a result has been returned from the server).

```
apex.server.process("SOME_PROCESS").done(function(pData){
  var result2 = doSomethingWithResult(pData);
  $s('Px_ITEM1', result2);
});
```

**NOT** something along the lines of:

```
apex.server.process("SOME_PROCESS").done(function(pData){
  var result = pData;
});

var result2 = doSomethingWithResult(pData);
$s('Px_ITEM1', result2);
```

Additionally, note that apex.server.process by default expects back a JSON string. Not doing so will cause an error to pop up. If you don't want to change your return values in the processes called, you can change the expected datatype to text:

```
apex.server.process("SOME_PROCESS", {}, {dataType:"text"})
```

Comment: Nice explanation Tom!

Comment: Great explanation Tom. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome explanation! However a small correction.
htmldb_Get can work asynchronously. Instead of calling get(), we have to call GetAsync() and pass the callback function.

Comment: @ArijitKanrar that's correct, but I didn't feel it was worth pointing out because: mostly, people use the Get because they saw it on the web somewhere and are not versed enough in the technicalities of it. Most won't dive in the javascript files. The api is not documented and has by now been well deprecated, doesn't matter if it's async or not. So as to not confuse or confound anyone I just omit the unpopular and unknown GetAsync (in contrast to Get). Much better to all hop aboard the ajax and promises train!